# A diamond inside a box of asterisk. An array program for Java, cmd

Tags: java

Enter number: " " <- if I enter 7 here, the output will be 7x7 box of asterisk. But the condition is Inside that box of asterisk, there is a Diamond.

```
*******
*** ***
**   **
*     *
**   **
*** ***
*******
```

What is the Program for this using an array? "import java.io.*......"

Comment: Please re-write your question to appear it as a question. For now it does not appear as a SO relevant question and most probably will be closed.

Comment: What problem're you having with writing the program?

Comment: I guess this is a homework or something :p

Answer (score 2):

I won't give full code because this looks like homework, but here's an outline of one possible algorithm you could use.

For each position `(i, j)` in your grid calculate the [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from the center of your diamond. If it exceeds the "radius" of the diamond, print a `*` otherwise print a space.

If the center of the diamond is `(x, y)` the Manhattan distance to the position `(i, j)`  is given by this formula:

```
int distanceFromCenter = Math.abs(x - i) + Math.abs(y - j);
```

Note that if you use the formula for the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) instead of the Manhattan distance you will get a circle instead of a diamond, though it might be difficult to see the difference between these two shapes at a 7x7 resolution.

Comment: Not sure that a Manhattan distance should be calculated, there might be an easier way just counting the number of lines, don't you think so ?

Comment: @BaL: This is just one approach of many. Personally I like it this approach because it's very simple and requires very few lines of code. There are no complex expressions, boundary conditions or special cases. It's also very easy to adjust the size or position of the diamond, change it to another shape (circle, oval, etc) or even have multiple (possibly overlapping) shapes - all with very few changes to the code. However other solutions are certainly possible and have different advantages (e.g. better performance).

Comment: This isn't a homework. We are just asked to Analyze the program for this. So, we are just asked to have a research of the program. So could you help me? Could you give me the program for this?

Comment: @user1557225: Who asked you and why? I don't want to post the full code unless I know why you need it.

Comment: The one who Substituted our Professor. 'Twas Already Time so He asked us to Study the program for this for our own sake before he Dismissed us.

Comment: So it's a homework :p
@MarkByers: yes I agree, I just thought that computing distances can be computing expensive whereas computing simple line numbering expression (`if/else`) might be more lightweight.

Comment: It isn't to be Submitted. Okay? I just would like to have an Idea regarding this.

Comment: It's up to us, if we would study this or not. So if you wouldn't mind giving me the codes. Okay fine.

Comment: I would suggest you to come up with a code and then we could help you correcting it ! Seems fair, no ? :-)